# Java generics and classcastexception

Tags: java, generics, rx-java2, classcastexception

not sure whats wrong here, but haven't used generics for a while, so its probably something I don't remember, but basically this code is "supposed to" work as far as I'm concerned, yet it does not:

```
public static class MyModel {}

protected static <T extends MyModel> FlowableTransformer<Response<T>, T> convert(Class<T> responseClass) {
    return observable -> observable.map((Function<Response<T>, T>) response -> {
        MyModel m = new MyModel();
        return (T)m;
    });
}
```

When using this, I get a Classcastexception at runtime. Basic idea would be that the method could return with either a "MyModel" or any of its subclasses (so T extends MyModel). Yet it cannot return with MyModel itself now?

Obviously just the gist of the problem and not actual code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: every T is a MyModel, not every MyModel is a T

Comment: That is a misuse of generics. Your method should just return `MyModel` instead of `T`. With generics, the caller gets decide what type you return, but in your code, the callee is deciding what type to return.

Comment: `m` is an instance of `MyModel` that you have constructed. Are you expecting JVM to change it to one of its subclasses (`T`) without problem?

Comment: "Not every MyModel is a T". I'm not following you. T is any subclass of MyModel. So by downcasting you always get a MyModel from any T

Comment: `T extends Animal` means any subclass of `Animal`. `Animal m = new Animal()`, then casting it to `Dog` - what do you think? This is what @Stultuske means - Every Dog is an Animal, not every Animal is a Dog.

Comment: if you use `new Fruit()`, you create a Fruit. Not a Banana, Not an Apple. Not a Peach. So, if you try to use the Fruit you created as an Apple, that won't work, because a Fruit is not an Apple. An Apple is a Fruit, but that is irrelevant here, since what you create is a Fruit, and you're trying to use it as if it was an Apple.

Comment: But Fruit is an Apple. You can use Fruit instead of Apple, and that wont change Apple being an Apple. It's irrelevant that in real life a "fruit is not an apple" because upcasting and downcasting exists in Java.

Comment: "But Fruit is an Apple" - No. An Apple is a Fruit, but a Fruit is not always an Apple. For example, a Pear is also a Fruit, but it's not an Apple. So if you try to treat it as if it's an Apple, you get problems. Casting is not magically going to convert a Pear to an Apple.

Comment: @breakline There is up and downcasting, but you have made a `Fruit`, you cannot say, let's assume this generic `Fruit` is an `Apple`! You can create an `Apple`, then downcast it to `Fruit`, then upcast back to `Apple`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have these 3 classes:

```
public class A {}

public class B extends A {}

public class C extends B {}
```

and the following function:

```
public static <T extends A> T foo() {
    A ret_val = new A();
    return (T)ret_val;
}
```

The following code will work correctly, without any exception:

```
A obj = foo();
```

because, here the `ret_val` inside `foo()` method is casted to `A` which is the actual type of `ret_val`.

But the following code will throw an exception:

```
B objB = foo(); // throws ClassCastException exception
C objC = foo(); // throws ClassCastException exception
```

because, what you are trying to do here, is casting an object of type `A` to `B`(or `C`), which is illegal.